# Spring boot deferred result is giving AsyncRequestTimeoutException in response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm developing a spring boot application in which there is a business requirement in which I have to keep calling an external API until I get Http status 204 No Content from that. However, this process is very time consuming so I'm using the deferred result in my controller method so that I can release the server thread but keep the browser connection alive.
But after hitting the endpoint of my application I'm getting this exception in response after sometime

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-08T12:43:31.560+0000",
    "status": 503,
    "error": "Service Unavailable",
    "message": "No message available",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.context.request.async.TimeoutDeferredResultProcessingInterceptor.handleTimeout(TimeoutDeferredResultProcessingInterceptor.java:42)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResultInterceptorChain.triggerAfterTimeout(DeferredResultInterceptorChain.java:79)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startDeferredResultProcessing$5(WebAsyncManager.java:424)\r\n\tat java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.onTimeout(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:150)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncListenerWrapper.fireOnTimeout(AsyncListenerWrapper.java:44)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.timeout(AsyncContextImpl.java:133)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:153)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:241)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\n",
    "path": "/api/datasync"
}
```

but the process of calling the external API and consuming the response continues even after getting the above error response. However, no exception or errors are logged in the server.log

Here is my controller function

```
@GetMapping("/documentinfo/datasync")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> getData(@RequestParam(name = "update", required = false, defaultValue = "no") String manuallyInvoked) throws Exception {
            log.info("Inside getData Method. Delegating request to Service Layer");
                    log.info("Manually invoked by user");
                    
                    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> result = new DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>>();
                    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
                    forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
                        log.info("Inside Pool");
                        result.setResult(new ResponseEntity<String>(dataImportService.getData(),HttpStatus.OK));
                    });
                    
                    log.info("Finished Importing data");
                    return result; 
}
```

Here dataImportService.getData() is my service layer method that calls the queue and consumes data.

Comment: I think you have provided some delay inside method execution. That means use a thread inside this method. According to my opinion, the problem is you don't give enough time to process this method.

Comment: @BawanthaWickramarachchi No, I haven't added any dealy. The method in the service layer is simple It calls the external API and saves the response

Comment: Yeah, that might be the issue. In order to call external API you have to give some time for that. Refer to asynchronous methods in java. This is the technique used inside this kind of methods.

Comment: But even after getting the error response, the process continues and it fetches data from external API and saves it into the database.

Answer (score 1):

specify `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` in application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  mvc:
    async:
      request-timeout: 30m
```